# What is the difference/relation between 'yum check-updates' and 'yum list updates'?

Tags: fedora, yum

What is the difference/relation between `yum check-updates` and `yum list updates`?

When use one over the other?

**Note** Yes I know that `dnf` should be used, but for research/academic purposes `yum` is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of these commands on my Fedora 36 system is exactly the same. `check-update` can return exit code 100 when updates are available, `list updates` doesn't do that and returns `0`.

`check-update` can also show changelogs for packages via the `--changelogs` option.

It's all in `man dnf`.

Comment: Yes, I have the same output, it mostly just after of the `sudo yum update` command execution - both commands returns nothing - previous of the `sudo yum update` command execution seems similar the output - well it is very long